# Resample time series in SQLite

Tags: query, sqlite, datetime, time

I have following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE entries (
  utc TEXT,
  entry INTEGER
);
```

with following data:

```sql
INSERT INTO entries
  (utc, entry)
VALUES
  ('2022-10-01 01:54', 23),
  ('2022-10-04 02:40', 46),
  ('2022-10-09 16:20', 51),
  ('2022-10-10 04:05', 81),
  ('2022-10-16 12:26', 78);
```

How can I write a query to get the daily value (linear interpolated) like this:

```
utc              | entry
-----------------|------
2022-10-01 00:00 | …
2022-10-02 00:00 | …
2022-10-03 00:00 | …
…                | …
```

Here is a pre-filled dbfiddle for playing around: https://dbfiddle.uk/TCX9Rd5t

Comment: Are you  trying to fill the missing dates ? Why is the entry column in the expected result empty ?

Comment: Some combination of this (https://www.sqlite.org/series.html) and this (https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) should get you in the right direction.

Comment: @ErgestBasha The entry column is not supposed to be empty, but I don't know the values since they are supposed to be calculated by the query I'm looking for (and I'm too lazy to calculate them by hand ^^).

Comment: @adius What do you mean by `but I don't know the values since they are supposed to be calculated by the query I'm looking for` ? If you have two entries for date `2022-10-01` let's say 23 and 55 , would the result be `2022-10-01 00:00 | 78` ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha I basically want to this in SQLite: https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/interpolate/linear/